# Can I use a high-voltage flash with the Cactus v5 trigger that is mounted on the camera?

Tags: hotshoe-flash, wireless-triggers, cactus

Can I use a high voltage flash (with a trigger voltage over 5V) on the [Cactus v5](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/cactus-wireless-flash-transceiver-v5-duo.html) transceiver that is mounted on the hot-shoe of my Canon 550D?

I know that I can mount the trigger on the camera and mount the high voltage flash on a separate receiver and fire away safely. The transceivers are not physically connected with each other and there is no way of the high voltage from the flash reaching the camera.

However, when I mount the flash on the transceiver that is on the camera will the transceiver pass through the high voltage to my camera, or will it somehow block the high voltage?

Comment: Well, the top hot-shoe is not a simple pass-through, and I can't see an electrical path back to the base shoe from the switched shoe (or mini plug) except for the ground, so it *should* be safe in theory. Am I going to tell you to test it on your camera for giggles? Nope.

Comment: You could probably hook up a voltmeter to the hotshoe on your Cactus v5 while you fire the flash (from the camera, not the test button on the flash as they might work differently) to see if any dangerous voltage is there. That's still no guarantee, but it's a start.

Comment: First off why would you want direct lighting on your subject? good for forensics and macro work and thats about it LOL I have an old strobeframe that I attach to the camera base and the flash on the other side so I have it all in one unit still use the V5's wirelessly. I use old Sunpak 611's. There are also many aftermarket TTL flashes out there now under 75.00 for your camera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The sync voltage limit on a Cactus V5 is 300V](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/blog/2011/01/1164/). As long as your flash doesn't go over that, you should be fine.

In addition, any dRebels that are newer than the 300D have a sync volt limit of 250V on the hotshoe, [according to Chuck Westfall](http://digitaljournalist.org/issue0703/tech-tips.html), the technical rep for Canon, answering a question in a 2007 tech tips article for the digitaljournalist.org:

> **I recently posted a question regarding the safe maximum sync voltage for an EOS 30D on http://www.openphotographyforums.com/. A reply led
>   me to an article called Tech Tips answering a number of Canon-related
>   FAQ. You addressed the safe sync voltage for a number of models,
>   including the 20D, but I was wondering where I might be able to find
>   published data on the safe sync voltages for the entire range of Canon
>   cameras (or maybe just the 30D, as that's the body I'm using now).**
>
> It's likely you'll never see an official list of all Canon SLRs
>   according to this specification, because Canon Inc. (our parent
>   company in Japan) simply doesn't do things like that. I've been with
>   Canon USA since 1982, so I'm in a pretty good position to know Canon
>   Inc.'s habits. However, I'll be happy to provide you with my
>   unofficial list:
>
> **Canon Digital SLRs safe for TCV up to 250 volts:** EOS-1D Mark II N, EOS-1D Mark II, EOS-1Ds Mark II, EOS-1D, EOS-1Ds EOS 30D, 20D, 5D EOS
>   Digital Rebel XTi, XT (400D/350D) EOS D6000/D2000, Kodak DCS560/DCS520
>   (circa 1998) EOS-DCS series (circa 1995)
>
> **Canon Digital SLRs safe for TCV up to 6 volts:** EOS 10D, D60, D30 EOS Digital Rebel (300D)
>
> **Canon 35mm SLRs safe for TCV up to 250 volts:** EOS-1V, EOS-1N, EOS-1, EOS 3
>
> **Canon 35mm and IX240 SLRs safe for TCV up to 6 volts:** EOS 650, 620, 630, RT EOS 850, 750, 700 EOS Rebel Series EOS Elan Series EOS
>   10s, A2E, A2 EOS IX, IX Lite T90
>
> Canon SLRs released earlier than the T90 did not have TTL flash
>   circuits, and comprehensive information on safe TCV levels is not
>   available.
>
> The trigger circuit voltage (TCV) rating for any EOS SLR is the same
>   on the hot shoe as it is on the PC terminal (if the camera has one),
>   but the acceptable TCV level varies according to the camera model.
>   Incidentally, the main reason for the difference is the way the X-sync
>   signal is generated. With the 250V cameras, the X-sync signal is
>   generated electronically. With the 6V cameras, the X-sync signal is
>   generated mechanically. There are no guarantees, but going forward I
>   anticipate that most if not all future EOS SLRs will be safe for TCV
>   up to 250 volts.

Comment: Why is this down voted? Is the information presented not correct? If so, please point that out in a comment when down voting.

Comment: Doesn't answer whether the cactus v5 trigger can be used as a safesync or not - which is the core of the question.